# How to split up modules for each react-router path with browserify

Tags: reactjs, browserify, react-router

I know the code split and tree shaking capabilities of `browserify` are not as good as the ones offered by `webpack` but for the moment I'm stuck with it.

Browserify also offers some plugin support for code splitting and I wonder how it would need to be setup to split modules based on a react-router configuration like the following

```
<Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/products/:id component={Product}/>
<Route path="/about" component={About}/>
<Route path="/search component={Search}/>
```

Except for `/about` every one of those could be a direct entry point to the app.

There is [Factor-Bundle](https://npmjs.org/package/factor-bundle) could that handle it?